# Default AppCompatButton not writing in all caps

Tags: android

I have the support library added as a dependency

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'`

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and my buttons themselves:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="RETURN"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

The button currently looks like this: [image]

Also note how I have set the text to all caps but it's getting overwritten with normal lettering. Is the style being overridden somewhere?

I have tried adding:

`style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"` to the button but nothing has happened. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: where is textAllCaps attribute ?

Comment: Whoops... been a long day. That was the problem, do you want to make this an answer? I feel really smart right now @Blackbelt
I thought textAllCaps was true by default, must have changed

Comment: somebody did it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:textAllCaps="true"` attribute to the Button